# DD4T2 Java: Get schema of Page object

Tags: dd4t, java

In my java project using DD4T 2 beta, I would like to get the Page Schema object from a page object.

Unfortunately, the Page interface (https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/dd4t-api/src/main/java/org/dd4t/contentmodel/Page.java) does not provide a getter for the schema. 
However, the schema object appears to be available in the page implementation classes, since it inherits from the BaseRepositoryLocalItem (https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/b3799b2869de908c05cddd969a0d4fc048448441/dd4t-core/src/main/java/org/dd4t/contentmodel/impl/BaseRepositoryLocalItem.java)

This means that, if i want to access the Schema property, I should cast my Page object to a PageImpl object.
Is this the correct way to do it, or is there a better way ?

some sample code

```
public function getPageSchema(org.dd4t.contentmodel.Page genericPage)
{
    // omitted null checks & checks that genericPage is of type PageImpl
    Schema pageSchema = ((PageImpl)genericPage).getSchema();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right - the repositorylocalitem interface doesn't expose the necessary getSchema() method you'd expect to see based on the implementation. This would be the correct way out indeed.

On a side note, could you raise a bug at dd4t-2 for this? It's a simple enough fix to include in the framework.

Comment: or solve it, and create a pull request :)

Comment: Fixed in version 2.0.6.